# Auto-size pane in JavaFX like scene builer have

Tags: javafx, resize, scenebuilder

I creating site builder and I want anchorpane at center of another pane. I have 3 anchor panes in SplitPane and in the central pane I need rezise of object like scene builder have when you resize scene builder. How to make that resizing? Is it very hard? I want to make this in fxml or directly in scene builder. I use IntelliJ.

This picture is show how it look when you open at first time and it need to be always 16:9 (central pane). Maybe you know what pane can be it
[image: this need]

And this is how it look when you open in full-screen
[image]

In this example I tried to use borderPane and I put empty anchorpane's in all other corners because when you put something in center it fit all borderPane. How I remember when you do this thing in anchorPane with constraints (like 100px from upper corner) it looks the same.
How to do normal 16:9 all-time resizing?

Comment: I think I need to do this pane in only one size at directly center with no resizing like in scene builder

Comment: You'd likely have to add listeners to the width and height and then modify the constraints of the child node to match a 16:9 ratio. Not sure if you could do this solely in FXML (i.e., you might need code for this; it would be cleaner that way anyway). A more robust solution would be to create your own layout (i.e., subclass `Region` or `Pane` and then override `layoutChildren()` and the `compute[Pref|Min|Max][Height|Width](...)` methods, perhaps with the content bias set so the height depends on the width).

Comment: See also [_Gluon Scene Builder: Scene Builder Kit_](https://github.com/gluonhq/scenebuilder#scene-builder-kit).